# Fast Swap64 Function in Delphi

Tags: delphi, assembly, swap

I'm using the following function to swap a (un)signed 64-bit integer value:

```
function Swap64(I: Int64): Int64;
begin
  Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[0] := Int64Rec(I).Bytes[7];
  Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[1] := Int64Rec(I).Bytes[6];
  Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[2] := Int64Rec(I).Bytes[5];
  Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[3] := Int64Rec(I).Bytes[4];
  Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[4] := Int64Rec(I).Bytes[3];
  Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[5] := Int64Rec(I).Bytes[2];
  Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[6] := Int64Rec(I).Bytes[1];
  Int64Rec(Result).Bytes[7] := Int64Rec(I).Bytes[0];
end;
```

How can I do the same thing in ASM to make it faster?

Comment: In either case, there is a `bswap` instruction you can use.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `bswap` instruction to swap bytes. For 32 code, you need to swap the bytes 32 bits at a time, with two uses of `bswap`. For 64 bit code, you can operate on a 64 bit register directly, and swap all 8 bytes with one use of `bswap`.

Here is a function for both 32 and 64 bit targets:

```
function ByteSwap64(Value: Int64): Int64;
asm
{$IF Defined(CPUX86)}
  mov    edx, [ebp+$08]
  mov    eax, [ebp+$0c]
  bswap  edx
  bswap  eax
{$ELSEIF Defined(CPUX64)}
  mov    rax, rcx
  bswap  rax
{$ELSE}
{$Message Fatal 'ByteSwap64 has not been implemented for this architecture.'}
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

I cannot say whether or not this function will lead to any discernible performance benefit. Before optimising code, you should identify bottlenecks by profiling and timing your code.

Comment: `CPUX86` directive was introduced in Delphi XE2, so `CPU386` is preferable.

Comment: @user that depends really. If you don't need to support such old versions then it's fine as I have it. The asker didn't state a version. If the asker is using pre XE2 version the conditionals are not needed at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Delphi ASM at all, but shouldn't you push those registers on the stack before touching them? Or does a function do a full register push when it starts?

Comment: @Blindy Delphi asm isn't the issue. It's the platform that defines the ABI. And no, those registers are volatile. They are used to return the value to the caller. You see identical code in Serg's answer.

Comment: I wasn't implying you were wrong, just wondering. As far as I know EDX is used by normal code generation and you might overwrite it with no warning is all (unless of course the function intro pushes it to the stack first).

Comment: @Blindy The platform ABI defines these rules, and eax, ecx and edx are volatile. In this case, eax and edx are used for return value. If the caller is using them, the caller needs to save and restore, because they are volatile.

Answer (score 4):

For 32-bit compiler:

```
function Swap64(I: Int64): Int64;
asm
        MOV     EDX,I.Int64Rec.Lo
        BSWAP   EDX
        MOV     EAX,I.Int64Rec.Hi
        BSWAP   EAX
end;
```