# Converting this inline Assembler function to Delphi Pascal

Tags: delphi, assembly, pascal, cpu-registers, translate

I am currently working on a legacy product in Delphi that includes some inline assembly, I need help understanding what the function does and how to convert it to Pascal.

The code is:

```
function lswap(i : longint) : longint; assembler;
asm
{$IFDEF CPU64}
    mov eax,ecx
{$ENDIF CPU64}
    db $0f,$c8  {bswap eax  !! requires at least 486 CPU!!}
end;
```

Comment: You may find more information here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33586049/576719

Comment: You can do a websearch for what bswap does, that's what I would do. Just type bswap into a search engine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - in the code bswap appears to be commented out - so why would the OP think of searching for what bswap does?

Comment: @RobLambden, The `bswap` instruction was perhaps not included in the actual Delphi version, but with the `db` you can express the instruction as well. So the comment is describing the inline command with the intel mnemomic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of helping you to understand what this does:

You can use the debugger to look at what is happening in your code, including in assembler.

If you have a test program that calls this routine (probably multiple times with different arguments) and stores the result in a standard Delphi variable then to debug you would:

- set a breakpoint where you first call it
- when you hit the breakpoint ensure you have your debug to 'Full CPU' and also choose 'mixed source' display.

Look at the code the compiler has produced.  The first thing the compiler will do is prepare the arguments for the routine you are calling.  For Pascal routines this normally means putting the values into appropriate CPU registers.

Step into the code line by line.  In the Registers window (part of the full cpu display) you will see the values of the registers and how they are changed with each instruction.

On return from the routine the compiler will store the result somewhere so you will be able to understand how the compiler is interpreting the result.

Simply looking at the input and output may be enough for you without having to understand everything in the routine.

Inline assembler has been widely used in lots of code-bases but with an increasing move away from a fixed x86 architecture there are an increasing number of reasons to remove such code.

Comment: In this case it's important to make sure your debugger is showing register values in hex, but yes, that's a good approach.  The other key thing is that you can look up instruction mnemonics in the manual to see what they do.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bswap

Comment: But without any ASM knowledge this would just be a blackbox test: I know it's supposed to swap something - now I have to find out what and to which extent. With my test results I then assume how a Pascal function may look like - but I wouldn't be 100% sure either.